issues with Face api (js)
I have been trying to create an HTML application that can detect if the face shown in the camera is similar to another one that you upload. However, I encountered several issues that I couldn't resolve:
Error Messages:
fr-index.html:52 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: faceapi is not defined at loadModels (fr-index.html:52:13) at fr-index.html:83:5 loadModels @ fr-index.html:52 (anonymous) @ fr-index.html:83 Promise.then (anonymous) @ fr-index.html:83 Understand this error index.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at index.js:2:23

I believe these errors might be related to the way I am loading the Face API library or how I am using its functions.
Here is my code (thanks in advance!):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Camera Comparison</title>
        <style>
            video,
            canvas,
            img {
                max-width: 45%;
            }
            canvas {
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Camera</h2>
        <video id="video" autoplay playsinline></video>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

        <h2>Upload Image</h2>
        <input type="file" id="imageUpload" accept="image/*" />
        <img id="uploadedImage" />

        <button id="compareButton">Compare Images</button>

        <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/face-api.js"></script>
        <script>
            const video = document.getElementById("video");
            const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            const imageUpload = document.getElementById("imageUpload");
            const uploadedImage = document.getElementById("uploadedImage");
            const compareButton = document.getElementById("compareButton");
            let uploadedFaceData;

            function startVideo() {
                navigator.mediaDevices
                    .getUserMedia({ video: true })
                    .then((stream) => {
                        video.srcObject = stream;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error("Error accessing the camera: ", err);
                        alert("Could not access the camera.");
                    });
            }

            async function loadModels() {
                await Promise.all([
                    faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri("/models"),
                    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("/models"),
                    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("/models"),
                ]);
            }

            imageUpload.addEventListener("change", async (e) => {
                const file = e.target.files[0];
                if (file) {
                    const img = await faceapi.bufferToImage(file);
                    uploadedImage.src = img.src;
                    uploadedFaceData = await faceapi
                        .detectSingleFace(img)
                        .withFaceLandmarks()
                        .withFaceDescriptor();
                }
            });

            compareButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
                const capturedFaceData = await faceapi
                    .detectSingleFace(video)
                    .withFaceLandmarks()
                    .withFaceDescriptor();

                if (!uploadedFaceData || !capturedFaceData) {
                    alert("No faces detected in one or both images.");
                    return;
                }

                const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(uploadedFaceData);
                const result = faceMatcher.findBestMatch(
                    capturedFaceData.descriptor
                );
                alert(result.toString());
            });

            loadModels().then(startVideo);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>



You are loading NPM module. Check how to do it in web

Could it be that you are hosting this yourself and are trying to load the models incorrectly?
try :
async function loadModels() {
  await Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri("/models"),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("/models"),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("/models"),
  ]);
}

And not: your loadFromUri("/models")
Also this tutorial might help you: https://itnext.io/face-api-js-javascript-api-for-face-recognition-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-bcc2a6c4cf07
